# Tkprof in critical environments

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Why tkprof utility is not adviced to be used in production setups? What concerns does it have?

Comment: Where do you find such an advice? can you gibe us a link or reference?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that tkprof is the problem. It is a tool that summarizes information from trace file. Tracing is the problem. If you enable tracing of a process, this may slow down the process considerable. Besides that the trace files may fill up your disks. Finally you should be aware  that security relevant information is written to trace files.